# Maintaining different session ids on the same browser for same application having 2 different portals which is logged in

Tags: spring, session, redis

I have a application which consists of 2 different portals as publishser and 
developer.I login into these with the URL's as http://localhost:8080/apiconnect/pubportal/ie and http://localhost:8080/apiconnect/devportal/ie/dev. Once i login to both, 2 different session ids/keys should get generated on redis server.But when checked sessiond id1 is getting deleted, so session id2 is active and remains on redis server which is not right.Hence please suggest solutoion or approach to overcome this.

Comment: does anyone in the group know the solution

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you simply have two separate applications, each maintaining its own session.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "overcome this", but if the goal is to have a single, unified session, then you're looking to implement a Single Sign-On solution.

There are of course a number of tutorials out there about SSO with Spring, so that would be a good place to start.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want something to be done on redis server since the applications running on different portals